# Type 'Error' constrained to non-protocol type even the type is a protocol

Tags: swift2, reactive-cocoa

I tried to extend SignalType from ReactiveCocoa with a where cause constrained error to a custom ErrorType, the code looks like this

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
    // .. cases
}

extension SignalType where Error: MyError {
    // my exetensions her
}
```

But I keep getting error like this

```
Type 'Error' constrained to non-protocol type 'MyError'
```

This is really odd, if you look at `ErrorType` definition

```
public protocol ErrorType {
}
```

As it's a protocol, then why the compiler complaining it's a `non-protocol` type, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, but `MyError` is not a protocol, which is what the error says.

When you use this syntax:

```
extension SignalType where Error: MyError
```

You're saying: extension for any `SignalType` whose `Error` **conforms** to `MyError`. But that's impossible. What you need is:

```
extension SignalType where Error == MyError
```

Which reads: extension for any `SignalType` whose `Error` **is** `MyError`.

Comment: yep, you're right, thank you. by the way I fixed my typo, `MyErrorError` should be `MyError` instead